# How to read NSString with accents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I need to compare an NSString that that has foreign accents, like á, à, ã, ç, ô, é, í, etc., but logging the string messes up the characters that have the accents.

How do I pass the entire NSString for comparison, like this:

```
if (myString == @"Elevação")

    { 
     do something nice...    
    }
```

The logging I'm getting, using `NSLog(@"myString = %@", myString);` from the above code is `myString = Eleva..o`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you saying you want to just log the value normalized or would you like to also do a normalized comparison?

Comment: Strings should be compared using `- [NSString isEqualToString:]`

Comment: I'd like to do a normalized comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `[someString isEqualToString:someOtherString];`

Comment: See also UTF-16 encoding for NSStrings.

Comment: Both options: 1) if ( [myString compare:@"Elevação" options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) and 2) [someString isEqualToString:someOtherString]; worked perfectly! Thanks a lot guys! Here I have the best Objective-C teachers!

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
if ( [myString compare:@"Elevação" options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame )
```

Comment: Both options: 1) if ( [myString compare:@"Elevação" options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) and 2) [someString isEqualToString:someOtherString]; worked perfectly! Thanks a lot guys! Here I have the best Objective-C teachers!

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two `NSString` pointers via `==` in Objective-C will only succeed if both sides of the comparison are the same instance of the same string.

If you want the expression to evaluate to true if the strings might be two different `NSString` instances with the same contents, you need to use `NSString`'s `isEqualToString:` method (as MrMusic suggested).

I'm not sure how to print arbitrary unicode text to the log. You might consider temporarily adding a UILabel in your interface for debugging purposes and setting its `text` property to your string.

Comment: Both options: 1) if ( [myString compare:@"Elevação" options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) and 2) [someString isEqualToString:someOtherString]; worked perfectly! Thanks a lot guys! Here I have the best Objective-C teachers!